# As I have want to do

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Stylistically, saying "as I have want to do." is preferable to me than "as I do." Is “as I have want to do." incorrect grammatically? Example, "My friends are quite aware of my vexatious flirting with women, as I have want to do."

Comment: as I have ***wont*** to do....

Comment: You don't use "have" with *wont*. Use the copula: *As I am wont to do*.

Answer (score 7):

First, as Jim has commented, the word is spelled "w**o**nt" (though it's pronounced the same way as *want* in a typical American accent).

*Wont* can be an adjective, as in *I am wont to use antiquated language*, or a noun, as in, *I spoke in a stilted style, as is my wont*.

Because *wont* can be a noun, it's probably the case that "have wont" is grammatical (although, it may be the case that *wont* requires an article). But even if it can be argued that "have wont" is grammatical, it is clearly the case that it is an unusual collocation. I found a number of examples of "have wont," but all were at least a hundred years old.

Take a look at this Ngram: [*have wont, am wont, my wont*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20wont%2Cam%20wont%2C%20my%20wont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20wont%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20wont%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20wont%3B%2Cc0)

So, if you want to use *wont*, the much more common phrasing would be, "I am wont to do."

That said, your sentence still doesn't quite work with "as I am wont to do," because the phrase "as I do" needs to describe a verb, not a gerund.  Let's leave aside *wont* for a moment: "They saw my flirting, as I always do..." is not correct.

Try, "My friends are quite aware of my vexatious flirting with women, which is my wont" or rephrase, "My friends are quite aware that I vexatiously flirted with the women, as I am wont to do."

Comment: My goodness, thank you so very much indeed. And thank you for being generous with you tone. It must be apparent to you that I like writing, yet lack the skills for same.I can now enjoy this new way of expressing myself and do it correctly. Joy!